# Raw transactions - SubtractFeeFromAmount flag

Tags: transactions, transaction-fees, raw-transaction, sendtoaddress

I'm currently working on a project (I'm a beginner in the world of cryptocurrencies) where we are using Raw Transactions, I want to know if in raw transactions there's a flag similar to subtractFeeFromAmount flag that exists in the sendToAddress method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you create a raw transaction, you must specify all inputs and outputs, and any leftover will go towards the fee (to the miner). ***The raw transaction does not do any fee calculation.***

Example Transaction:

```
input1: .1BTC
input2: .2BTC

output1: .299BTC
```

The resulting fee would be:

```
fee: .001BTC
```

This amount gets added to the coinbase transaction (by the miner) of the block which includes this transaction.